# How to do factorial in VHDL created with multipliers

Tags: vhdl, multiplication, factorial

I have 16 bit multiplier. I would like to create factorial function with bit operation. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Think about what a factorial does:

Starts with a number, multiplies that number by itself minus one.  Then multiplies that NEW number by itself minus two.  This process repeats until the new number is equal to one.  I would recommend setting up a pipeline where one multiply happens on each clock.  The running sum is stored to a signal that keeps getting larger and larger on each multiply.  Keep checking to make sure you're not at 1 yet, and if you are your factorial is done.

One other note... you'll need to constrain this design.  Think of the maximum number you're going to want to send to this factorial code and design for that.

Comment: I have maximum number. Input is only integer from 1 to 8.